# How is the following statement for true for this condition?

Tags: calculus, limits, discrete-mathematics, logic

Let f be some function for which you know only that

if $0 \lt \mid x-3\mid \lt 1$, then $\mid f(x)-5 \mid \lt 0.1$

How is this statement necessarily true?
' If $\mid x-2.5 \mid \lt 0.3$, then $\mid f(x)-5 \mid \lt 0.1$ '

Comment: This looks like a homework exercise, so I will reply with a hint. Think in terms of distances on the real line. You want to show that given that $|x-2.5|<0.3$ then you also have $0<|x-3|<1$.  Can you show this mathematically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but the other answers do not help you, maybe you're finding difficult the fact that $f$ is only characterized by an implication. This is just to be understood as $f$ is any function, but it is known that if ... then ....

Comment: It was a question in the textbook and there were multiple statements that can be true. I got the rest but did not understand how this could be true. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the first condition to make it clear:
if $2<x<4$ then $4.9<f(x)<5.1$. I.e. we the function must be somewhere in the rectangle defined by the points (2,4.9), (2,5.1), (4,5.1), (4,4.9) for values of x between 2 and 4.

Rewriting the statement to prove to make it clearer gives:
if $2.2<x<2.8$ then $4.9<f(x)<5.1$
This is contained within the larger rectangle we mentioned above so it is true.

Comment: Oh ok, it seems a lot clear when you rewrite it. Thank you